# Powershell array or objects

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pretty up my code a little (and as a result learn some things)

I have a pretty straight forward problem that I would like to solve with a foreach loop

but I don't know enough about powershell yet to execute it correctly

I have this text

```
$gr0 = get-adgroup -Properties * -Filter "(Name -eq 'Division 0')" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=solutions,DC=local";
$gr1 = get-adgroup -Properties * -Filter "(Name -eq 'Division 1')" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=solutions,DC=local";
$gr2 = get-adgroup -Properties * -Filter "(Name -eq 'Division 2')" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=solutions,DC=local";
```

I then go on to run a loop on the results of each group with identical code

what I'm trying to do  is

$groups[] = $gr0 $gr1 $gr2

foreach (group in groups) { do something;}

But I can seem to find any good examples

Any help at all would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the syntax of `foreach` in Powershell? Here is an example:

```
foreach ($group in $groups) {
  do something;
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is a way to perform your action in a loop:

```
$groups = @();
for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
  $groups += get-adgroup -Properties * -Filter "(Name -eq 'Division $i')" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=solutions,DC=local";
}
```

Reference:

- [ForEach (loop statement)](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)

Comment: actually I'm looking how to load the array properly so the foreach will step to each one

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to group your results together like this

```
$groups = @();
$groups += $gr0
$groups += $gr1
$groups += $gr2
```

You most likely have other reasons for doing it the way you do but you could also update your `-Filter` so it all returns in one object.

```
$groups = get-adgroup -Properties * -Filter "(Name -like 'Division*')" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=solutions,DC=local" | Where-Object{$_.Name -match "Division [012]"}
```

`-Filter` does not support the match operator. So grab all the ones that start with "Division" and pipe them into `Where-Object` to get the ones that are just Division 0,1,2. You could just omit the `Where` clause altogether depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
foreach ($groupname in 'Division 0','Division 1','Division 2')
 {
   $grp = get-adgroup -Properties * -Filter "Name -eq '$groupname'" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=solutions,DC=local"
   do stuff with $grp
 }
```

For Matt:

```
$groupnames = 'Division 0','Division 1','Division 2'
$NameFilters = $groupnames -replace '^','(Name=' -replace '$',')'
$Filter = "'(|$NameFilters)'"

foreach ($grp in get-adgroup -Properties * -LDAPFilter $filter -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=solutions,DC=local")
 {
   do something with $grp...
  }
```

$filter will be an OR'd LDAP filter of each of the group names:

```
'(|(Name=Division 0) (Name=Division 1) (Name=Division 2))'
```

Comment: I was going to edit my post with this. I would think that a single filter would be better. However if there is no relationship between the groups this is much better.

Comment: Left an example of creating a filter from a collection of arbitrary names.